# Using parentheses around a type in a template argument

Tags: c++, clang

I have a `void **` which I want to cast to a `class cv::Mat **` (the reason for using `void **` in C++ is that this code is for a C-C++ interface to OpenCV (which is C++-only, and I want to be able to use it from C code)).

I had this C-like expression which I wrote a long time ago:

```
(class cv::Mat **)img
```

Now I want to use a more C++-ish approach, and use the safer C++ casts (basically to make clang-tidy happy :).
For most of the code, I could do it with `static_cast<>` (for simple `void *`, but `void **` is requiring a more aggresive cast).

I tried:

```
dynamic_cast<class cv::Mat **>(img)
```

But clang complains:

```
/home/user/src/alx/libalx/src/cv/core/img/img.cxx:53:27: error: 'cv::Mat *' is not a class type [clang-diagnostic-error]
        return alx::CV::init_img(dynamic_cast<class cv::Mat **>(img));
                                 ^
```

Now, I guess that removing `class` from the expression would probably solve this issue.  But I don't like that solution.  I like the verbosity of the `class` and `struct` keywords, and I'd like to be able to keep it as much as possible.  I don't understand why is clang applying class to `cv::Mat *`, and not to `cv::Mat`; it doesn't make any sense to me, but hey, I'm a C guy, not a C++ guy, so I may ignore C++ weird things...

So I thought of trying to add parentheses to the expression, just to see if it works:

```
dynamic_cast<(class cv::Mat) **>(img)
```

This silenced the warning, but I'm worried that it may be doing something really awkward silently.  Are those parentheses doing what I wanted to do (i.e., make clang understand that `class` applies to the base type and not to the pointer)?  Or are they doing anything else (unwanted)?

Comment: `dynamic_cast` only works for polymorphic typecasts (ie, casting a pointer/reference to a base class into a pointer/reference to a derived class, but only for a single object at a time).  In your situation, if `static_cast` doesn't work, use `reinterpret_cast` instead, eg: `reinterpret_cast<cv::Mat**>(img)`

Comment: Here There Be Dragons.  You can `static_cast` a `void*`, but a `void**` is not a `void*`.  You'll need the bigger hammer `reinterpret_cast`, and tread very carefully.

Comment: Thanks!  `reinterpret_cast<class cv::Mat **>(img)` works as expected :-)
BTW, I love those dragons.  They allow me to use pure C++ code from within my beloved C.  I understand the dangers of it, though...

Comment: Adding those parentheses should just be an error: there are no precedence issues in this case for them to address, and it’s impossible for `class` to be interpreted as applying to a pointer type (or to do anything at all in this case unless there’s *also* a `cv::Mat` function or variable).

Comment: *"I guess that removing `class` from the expression would probably solve this issue."* -- why guess? Do it and see what happens. Don't trash a solution for style reasons when you can readily test it (then trash it for the reason that it doesn't work). ;)